# What is the most idiomatic way of handling errors in asynchronous handlers in actix-web?

Tags: rust, future, actix-web

I have an async handler in actix_web that must fail if several headers are not set. I don't understand what the best way of handling errors in functions that return `Future` should be. I basically want an equivalent of the `?` operator for futures.

This is my current code:

```rust
r.post().with_async(
    move |req: HttpRequest, path: Path<EventPath>, body: Json<EventCreationRequest>| {
        let headers = req.headers();
        let client_id = match headers
            .get("x-client-id")
            .ok_or("Header not found")
            .and_then(|v| v.to_str().map_err(|_| "Invalid header content"))
        {
            Err(e) => return ok(HttpResponse::BadRequest().body(e)).responder(),
            Ok(v) => v.to_string(),
        };
        operation_that_returns_future()
            .map(|_| HttpResponse::Ok().body("OK!"))
            .responder()
    },
);
```

I have solved the lack of a `?` operator for futures by matching an doing an early return. However, in my code I actually need to ensure that a bunch of other headers exist.

Ideally, I would like to extract the matching and early return logic to something reusable, but in this case that forces me to create a macro. That seems like a bit of an overkill, especially if there's already something in the language that allows me to do what I want.

What is the most idiomatic way of handling this situation?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MCVE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle errors, return a failing `Future`. For example, do the header check as a `Future`, then chain your futures with `.and_then`. A trick is to keep error types of futures the same, to avoid `map_err`. For example:

```rust
fn handler(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error> {
    has_client_header(&req)
        .and_then(|client| operation_that_returns_future(client))
        .map(|result| HttpResponse::Ok().body(result))
}

fn has_client_header(req: &HttpRequest) -> impl Future<Item = String, Error = Error> {
    if let Some(Ok(client)) = req.headers().get("x-client-id").map(|h| h.to_str()) {
        future::ok(client.to_owned())
    } else {
        future::failed(ErrorBadRequest("invalid x-client-id header"))
    }
}

fn operation_that_returns_future(client: String) -> impl Future<Item = String, Error = Error> {
    future::ok(client)
}
```

Result:

```
$ curl localhost:8000
invalid x-client-id header⏎
$ curl localhost:8000 -H 'x-client-id: asdf'
asdf⏎
```

When `operation_that_returns_future` has another error type:

```rust
fn handler(req: HttpRequest) -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error> {
    has_client_header(&req)
        .and_then(|client| {
            operation_that_returns_future(client)
                .map_err(|_| ErrorInternalServerError("operation failed"))
        })
        .map(|result| HttpResponse::Ok().body(result))
}
```

Another trick is to use the [failure crate](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/), which provides `failure::Error::from` that maps all errors to one type, `failure::Error`.

Lastly, you might find [`actix_web::guards`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.3/actix_web/guard/index.html) useful for checking header values:

```rust
.guard(guard::Header("x-client-id", "special client"))
```